# Karate conditional background execution

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

How can I have a karate setup so that I can run a bunch of tests when running locally and a subset with running in pre-prod?

When I run the tests locally, I spin up a mock server and set it up using `Background`. In pre-prod, no mock server is required, so I would like to skip the `Background` execution.

Also, I was not able to use the @Before annotation to start my cucumber Test Runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tags. Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-tags

```
@preprod
Scenario: some scenario
```

Personally I prefer the approach where you spin up mock servers from your JUnit test classes, and there are a lot of examples, like this one: [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/mock/contract/ConsumerUsingMockTest.java)

But you can do this also, refer the docs on [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic):

```
* eval if (karate.env == 'preprod') karate.call('mock-start.feature')
```

> I was not able to use the @Before annotation

That's not really helpful, please follow the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue